# Move a Sprites location based on Touch

Tags: c#, ios, unity-game-engine

I need to take the input from a touch and then move a sprite to that location heres what I have so far

```
public class PlayerContoller : MonoBehaviour {
    public Sprite Hands;
    public Vector2 HandsLocation;


    void Start () {


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (Input.touchCount > 0){
            KnifeTouch ();
        }
    }
    void KnifeTouch () {
        Input.GetTouch(0).position = HandsLocation

    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: So what is the problem? Please describe exactly what is the problem and what you did in your code.

Comment: The problem is i can not figure out how to take the input from the vector 2 and make that the location of the sprite.  As for my code at first i create a vector 2 and sprite variable then when there is a touch on the screen it gets location of touch and put it into the vector2

Answer (score 1):

I didn't work with mono or unity3d, I work with XNA, but I think the rule is the same.

Your code:

> Input.GetTouch(0).position = HandsLocation

You try to set your HandsLocation to device input position?
I suppose you can read device input data and use it to your actions.

You need to do revers action:

> HandsLocation = Input.GetTouch(0).position

Now you store input data in your controller, then use it to move your sprite:

```
void Update () {
    if (Input.touchCount > 0){
        //KnifeTouch ();
        HandsLocation = Input.GetTouch(0).position; // store input position
    }
    // after read position, use it to move sprite
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Input.GetTouch().position return pixel coordinates to convert it into world coordinate write this code.

> Vector3 pos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.touches[0].position);

set pos.z to object.tranform.position.z and assign it to object

obj.transform.position = pos;